# In what locations can a subquery be used?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

In the following code I mark locations within a query where to my understanding a subquery can be used:

```
from   c1 in subquery
from   c2 in subquery
where  c2 = subquery
let    c3 = subquery
select new{ result = subquery };
```

Are there any other locations where a subquery can be used?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a subquery anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where subquery.Contains(value)
```

Comment: hi, could you explain the point you were trying to make with your example?

Comment: My point was that in addition to an equality check in a `where` clause, you can also apply operators to a subquery in a `where` clause.